# Is it possible to deploy a pre-trained machine learning model in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-caret

I'm wondering whether it's possible to deploy a pre-trained ML model in Shiny? The idea is that the model is there, the user can input some new values for a single observation, then the model can predict the outcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the ML model as an `RObject` and make it available in your global environment before loading `RShiny` application. I am not really sure about the potential pitfalls in doing this but to answer your question, sure, you can!!